# combining pcd maps

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am using Autoware v1.1 software in Ubuntu 16.04 (Kinetic) platform. Autoware software uses ROS functionalities. I want to combine/stitch 16 pcd files [eg. 1.pcd, 2.pcd, 3.pcd and so on] and create a global pcd file. When I upload pcd files for Mapping in Runtime Manager tab of the Autoware software, it gives me an overlapped map of those pcd files. I followed @wallizadaM and @kitsukawa [GitHub.com, issue #533, topic: Stitching the .pcd mapps] who were describing their method for combining pcd files. However, I don't have the ndt_localizer package which @wallizadaM suggested to manually combine pcd files and @kitsukawa method weren't suitable for my aim. Can you help me solve this problem? How can I combine or stitch muliple pcd files (local maps) to create a global pcd file?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/327597/combining-pcd-maps/) by [Badhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/43849/badhan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2019-07-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Take a look on the [libpointmatcher library](https://github.com/ethz-asl/libpointmatcher/blob/master/doc/index.md).
As it says:

> How to I build a global map from a
> sequence of scans? See the example
> `align_sequence.cpp`.

I think this contains what you need!

---

Originally posted by [kosmastsk](https://answers.ros.org/users/36854/kosmastsk/) with karma: 210 on 2019-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Badhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/43849/badhan/) on 2019-07-03**:
The link which you gave me doesn't open. I am unable to see the example align_sequence.cpp. Is align_sequence.cpp a source file of the Autoware software?

**Comment by [kosmastsk](https://answers.ros.org/users/36854/kosmastsk/) on 2019-07-03**:
The file is in [here](https://github.com/ethz-asl/libpointmatcher/blob/master/examples/align_sequence.cpp). It is a library totally different from Autoware, but it can handle .pcd files the way you want.

**Comment by [Badhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/43849/badhan/) on 2019-07-09**:
Hi. Thankyou for giving me the cpp file. However, I don't know how to use it for combining pcd files. Can you please help me on that?

**Comment by [Badhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/43849/badhan/) on 2019-07-25**:
The align.cpp file that you gave me only reads the point cloud data from a file and creates a map. I am looking for a package that will allow me to combine multiple pcd files containing point cloud maps into a pcd file containing the combined map generated from maps of multiple pcd files using that particular package. Can anyone help me??